# Volley error ( Unexpected response code 400) for get request with param

Tags: android, json, http, android-volley

This is my code

```
private void fetchDataFromServer() {
String JSON_URL = "http://example.com/www/api/v3/API.php?requestParams={ \"randohum\": \"cjjlsk\", \"ads\": [ { \"adViewId\": \"1376 \", \"isAdWall\": \"false\", \"sendRepeat\": \"false\", \"size\": \"10\", \"startIndex\": \"0\" } ], \"apiVersion\": \"3\", \"deviceLanguage\": \"en\", \"deviceX\": \"1080\", \"deviceY\": \"1776\", \"directImageUrl\": \"1\", \"subid1\": \"hello\", \"subid2\": \"how\", \"subid4\": \"you\", \"subid3\": \"are\", \"subid5\": \"fine\", \"idfa\": \"6D92078A - 8246 - 4BA4 - AW5B - 76104861E7DC\" , \"gaid\": \"d4f8030b - 4a52 - 4261 - 9830 - bd6c987cd261\", \"hashCode\": \"QEfsvgku8LSjssGSpSPNb+SissH0v878790dODTkiTAY+QO33OxEW\", \"isMobile\": \"true\", \"packageName\": \"009\",\"adWallId\":\"\",\"requestSource\":\"SDK\",\"dynamicPlacement\":\"false\" }";


StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
    new Response.Listener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(String response) {
              Log.v("MSG",response);
      }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.v("MSG",error.getMessage());
      }
    });
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

But i am getting :
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400.

For other url without requestParams it is working fine. I guess some problem with requestParams when integrated with volley.It working fine on browser or in postman.

Comment: Why are you putting `requestParams` inside the URL? That just looks wrong...

Comment: It is a GET request, and with one param. Key is "requestParams" and value is that json.

Comment: But why? Putting JSON into a GET request seems like a poor API design... And you can't have spaces in a URL anyway... Are you sure it isn't a POST request? Can you show a screenshot of it working in POSTman?